# ¿por qué no se puede acceder a las propiedades de una clase desde una función estática?

Tags: php, poo, funciones, objeto, class

Teniendo de referencia el siguiente ejemplo, ¿por qué no se puede acceder a las propiedades de la Clase desde la función cuando esta es estática? Gracias de antemano.

```
class Clase {
    
        public $valor = 'Hola Publico';
        
        public static function mostrarValor(){
            echo self::$valor;  
        }
}
    
Clase::mostrarValor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes definir valor como una variable estática

```php
class Clase {
    
        public static $valor = 'Hola Publico';
        
        public static function mostrarValor(){
            echo self::$valor;  
        }
}
    
Clase::mostrarValor();
```

Comment: gracias! Y por qué debe ser static para poder ser accesible? por qué no puede ser usado siendo non-static?

Comment: [una función static no puede acceder a variables no definidas como static y una funcion normal si puede](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php), la palabra reservada static esta destinada para poder accederse antes de instanciar una clase, dado que estas variables static no cambian su valor se asigna un espacio en memoria fijo al momento de correr la aplicación, mientras que si no es static esta variable podria cambiar y solo se puede saber su valor una ves instanciada la clase, las clases se guardan en memoria al ser instanciadas mientras que las static al correr el codigo.

Comment: @John Claro! Se puede usar únicamente su valor cuando la clase esté instanciada, pues a partir de ese objeto este valor no podrá cambiar. Comprendo. Muchas gracias!